# Using @angular-builder/custom-webpack to change a webpack property for Angular 13

Tags: angular, webpack, nrwl-nx, angular-builder

I am building an Angular 13 application inside a NX monorepo. This repo contains a react library that uses jsx files. When I run my app, the React library files don't resolve the jsx extension correctly (all of the import statements for jsx files need to end in '.jsx'). I think to solve this I need to add 'jsx' to the resolve.extensions array in webpack config. To do this I am using angular-builder's custom webpack package. First I installed the package:

`npm install --save-dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack@13`

Then I created a custom-webpack.config.js file in the application root with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js','min.js', 'jsx']
      }
  };
```

Next I replaced architect.build.builder in the angular json:
`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"` changed to `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"` I added the following to architect.build.options:

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
  "path": "custom-webpack.config.js",
  "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
},
```

I changed architect.serve.builder from `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"` to `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server"`

When I run the applicaiton, it builds and serves fine, but if I change the import statement to exclude '.jsx' it breaks
`export * from './lib/my-component'` breaks but `export * from './lib/my-component.jsx'` works.

Is my approach correct? Am I creating a custom webpack file and including it the right way?

Comment: I'm attempting to do almost the same thing in Ang 13, but in the context of putting together a prototype for the Azure Event Hubs TypeScript client. It's a total nightmare. I've installed custom-webpack (v13.1.0), and added the `extra-webpack.config.js` file, then referenced it within my angular.json as you did above.

Comment: I also just tried using the IndexTransformation, but my `ng serve` is crashing out on `.src.index.html`, and telling me that `no loaders are configured to process this file.` Also referring to this post: https://www.justjeb.com/post/customizing-angular-cli-build